# Using Magick++ library on windows

Tags: c++, imagemagick

The title is pretty self-explanatory... how do I build the source for Magick++ for Windows? I've tried everything, and followed ImageMagick's directions extensively. However, all of these instructions are outdated. How do I get the static link libraries for Magick++, the include directories, and the dynamic link libraries? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not familiar with windows platform, but I do remember ImageMagick's installer has a "Install developer headers & libraries for C and C++" checkbox under customize(?) options. If checked, the header files, dlls, & static libs are installed next to ImageMagick binaries under Program Files directory. If you want to BUILD this files from source, checkout [Github's repo](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-Windows).

Comment: ah ok! i didnt see that option! You are correct, thank you.

Comment: Great! Please post your solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted. It'll help future users searching for the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically it's super easy... Go to [this](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php) link here, download whichever version fits your platform, go through the setup, and when a bunch of options comes up click the one that says install developer libraries. The include directories and libs will be in wherever you chose to install it.